# Use two columns for FTS4 from sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I have a table with two columns (ldap, name). I want to be able to full text search any of those columns with the library FTS4. Here I have a couple of statements I'm using to create the virtual table but when I create a statement using Match the result is empty although it should return data.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_rep USING FTS4(ldap,name, content="__sales_rep");
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS __sales_rep___after_insert AFTER INSERT ON __sales_rep BEGIN INSERT INTO sales_rep (ldap, name) VALUES (new.ldap, new.name);END;
```

I am inserting a row (ldap, name) VALUES ('test', 'Bryan');
But using

```
SELECT * FROM sales_rep where name MATCH 'Bry';
```

The result is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting data in an external content FTS table requires to provide explicitly a value for the `docid`, which should be the `rowid` of the content table.

In your case you need to change the trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER  __sales_rep___after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON __sales_rep
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO sales_rep (docid, ldap, name)
  VALUES (new.rowid, new.ldap, new.name);
END;
```

Comment: I tried changing the trigger like that but the result was still empty. When I run 'SELECT * FROM sales_rep ;' it returns one row with the name Bryan but when I run 'SELECT * FROM sales_rep WHERE name MATCH "Br" ;' it comes empty

Comment: you should use a prefix match i.e.  `... MATCH "Br*" `

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much